# Aws::KMS::Errors::AccessDeniedException when putting data into s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have bucket set up, and kms id,  tried access the bucket and write some testing data to, somehow I kept getting aws::KMS::Errors::AccessDeniedException
here is the ruby code I wrote

```
  region = 'us-east-1'
  keyId = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxx:key/xxx"
  kms = aws::KMS::Client.new(region: region)
  client = aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new(
      region: region,
      kms_key_id: keyId,
      kms_client: kms
      )
      
   bucket = "test_bucket"
   item = "test_item"
   contents = "some testing"
    client.put_object(
        body: contents,
      bucket: bucket,
      key: item
```

Comment: Does your bucket policy state(reflect) this? *Check for a condition that allows uploads only when objects are encrypted by a certain AWS Key Management System (AWS KMS) key.*

Comment: Hi, does it mean all the update uploaded to s3 bucket has to be KMS encrypted?